# android UI freeze when load large string into the TextView

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm learning about Android UI thread and background thread how to processing data and how to background thread communicated with UI thread or vice-versa

For example, using a background thread, I will make one string having a length bigger compared to normal one.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= 9999; i++){
        builder.append(String.valueOf(i));
    }

    return builder.toString();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String str) {
    super.onPostExecute(str);
    tvdisplay.setText(str);
}
```

Now, when string set into TextView then UI freeze for some time how I can set string into the TextView without UI freeze? or what's an efficient way to load large string or data into the UI without hanging?

Answer (score 0):

You just keep your textview inside ScrollView..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"> 
       <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbLoading"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvdisplay"/> 
        </LinearLayout> 
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why? are you combining runOnUiThread with StringBuilder I think you know StringBuilder is not UI component.

Comment: because you can't perform actions on UI Thread from doInBackground() method from documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: I think you not exactly understand my question okay! you just take one string bigger one approx 2.5Mb and try to set into TextView, remember during one intermedia progressbar doing there work. now, observed what effect you can get.

Comment: you show your UI freeze for some time, if a string size is a more then more time your UI freeze, if you not have an answer then please upvoted question because other one give attention to this issue

Comment: My Ui is not freezing it's working properly, the UI which I have used, the textView is declared inside a ScrollView. Have you kept the textView inside a ScrollView

Comment: can you just put one intermedia progressbar into the liner layout

Comment: I just edited. Are you looking for that ? And it's also working perfect

Comment: You need to put another method `onPreExecute()` and in that set your `progressBar` visible and invisible in `onPostExecute()`.